# Is there any way to get complete user data from Facebook using webhooks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I am trying to create an application in which I would like to display feeds from multiple social media apps including Facebook ,Instagram ,Twitter. I would like to get the data live as much as possible so I thought of integrating Facebook's webhook in my project. I created a server side application with Facebook's authentication and I created a callback URL and configured it to webhooks in my meta developers app. I was able to get a json object every time a change happens in my feed. But I couldn't get the exact details about the change.

Every time if someone likes or comments on my Facebook profile I get a json object like this:

```
{
    "entry": [
      {
        "id": "10603189900****",
        "time": 1670853367,
        "uid": "10603189900****",
        "changes": [
          {
            "field": "feed"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "object": "user"
}
```

But it doesn't give any data that explains what the actual event occurred is. For instance, if someone commented on my posts I want to get the details on the post in which the event happened, the details about the person who commented it and also the whole texts of the comments.

I would like to know if there is any possibilities to get the whole data?

Comment: Not via the webhook, no. The purpose of that is to inform you _that_ something has changed - but not to provide you with the details. You will need to make additional API calls for those.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thank you. I have one more doubt regarding the comments. I tried to use Facebook's graph API in Graph API explorer to get the comments that other fb users posted on my posts. For example: "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me?fields=name%2Cposts%7Bid%2Ccomments%7Bfrom%2Cmessage%2Cobject%2Cparent%7D%7D&access_token=my_access_token"  by using this endpoint I was able to get the comments that I made on my own posts but couldn't get the comments made by other users. Is there any way to get the comments that were made by others on my profile?

Comment: Unless they were to log in to your app and grant it permission, I don't think there is.

Comment: I can't understand what you meant. Can you elaborate it please?

Comment: IIRC, Facebook will not expose user data, unless the user in question granted the requesting app permission. But the person that made the comment on your post, most likely did not do that. And I think somewhere in the documentation regarding comments it also says, a user can only read the comments made by themselves, not those of others.